# Python Turtle hold key function

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am attempting to make pong using Turtle, I have most things working, however, I would like to implement the ability to hold a key to move the bumpers up and down, rather than having to tap the key multiple times. These are my functions for movement so far.

```
def lbump_move_up():
    x = lbump.ycor()
    x += bumpspeed
    if x > 240:
        x = 240
    lbump.sety(x)

def lbump_move_down():
    x = lbump.ycor()
    x -= bumpspeed
    if x < -240:
        x = -240
    lbump.sety(x)

def rbump_move_up():
    x = rbump.ycor()
    x += bumpspeed
    if x > 240:
        x = 240
    rbump.sety(x)

def rbump_move_down():
    x = rbump.ycor()
    x -= bumpspeed
    if x < -240:
        x = -240
    rbump.sety(x)

turtle.listen()
turtle.onkey(lbump_move_up,'w')
turtle.onkey(rbump_move_up,'Up')
turtle.onkey(lbump_move_down,'s')
turtle.onkey(rbump_move_down,'Down')
turtle.onkey(ball_move,'Return')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer to this, as I came here looking for one myself. However, I have some progress on it that someone else could finish...

You can create a new class that calls like a recursive function as follows:

```
class function2:
    def __init__(self,fun,args=None):
        self.fun=fun
        self.args=args

    def begin_loop(self):
        self.looping=True
        self.loop()

    def loop(self):
        self.fun(self.args)
        if self.looping: self.loop()

    def end_loop(self):
        self.looping=False
```

Now to tie it to your example, you can convert your functions into function2s and thus call them onkeypress as follows:

```
l_up=function2(lbump_move_up)
r_up=function2(rbump_move_up)
l_down=function2(lbump_move_down)
r_down=function2(rbump_move_down)

Wn=turtle.Screen()

Wn.onkeypress(l_up.begin_loop,'w')
Wn.onkeypress(r_up.begin_loop,'Up')
Wn.onkeypress(l_down.begin_loop,'s')
Wn.onkeypress(r_down.begin_loop,'Down')

Wn.onkeyrelease(l_up.end_loop,'w')
Wn.onkeyrelease(r_up.end_loop,'Up')
Wn.onkeyrelease(l_down.end_loop,'s')
Wn.onkeyrelease(r_down.end_loop,'Down')

Wn.listen()
```

So to the issue: RecursionErrors

If you want your function to cause a small change, then you'll need to hold the button for a long time and that causes RecursionErrors - which at least in this case don't seem to be affected by try/except statements.

Once again, sorry for the incomplete solution, but I feel like you can probably get away with larger movements in pong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but found the "onkeypress" function in the Turtle documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.onkeypress), which resolved the issue for me.

```
turtle.onkeypress(fun, key=None)
```

"onkeypress", will move the turtle as long as the key is pressed, while "onkey" will move it once when the key is released.

Example:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

turtle = Turtle("turtle")
turtle.penup()
screen = Screen()
screen.listen()


def move_forward():
    turtle.forward(20)


def move_backward():
    turtle.backward(20)


screen.onkeypress(move_forward, "w")
screen.onkey(move_backward, "s")

screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).